# Write JSON parser to format data for pie chart (HighCharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, highcharts

I was fighting with HighCharts quite some hours for formatting the data input to the `series` option. 
Finally I saw the link [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8216335/1413598) solved my problem for data formatting and input.

The data format that would be recognized by HighCharts pie chart is like this `(format 1)` as indicated by the link above:

```
[["chrome",15],["firefox",20]]
```

I actually want **dynamic** data input from external URL and format the data so that HighCharts can recognized it. The data format I got from the URL is like this `(format 2)`:

```
[
    {
        "status": "Stopped \/ Idle",
        "val": 17.469444444444,
    }, {
        "status": "Working",
        "val": 0,
    }, {
        "status": "Headland Turning",
        "val": 0,
    }, {
        "status": "Transport",
        "val": 0.15333333333333,
    }
]
```

which is already in JSON format.

I just want to know that is that necessary for me to write a parser for the data from `format 2` to `format 1`? Or Am I missing something that HighCharts can recognize the JSON format data and I don't actually need to write a parser?

I am new to HighCharts so feel free to point that out if some of my problem description does not make sense..Thank you!

**EDIT**:  Thanks for all guys answering my question!

Comment: Keep in mind that the text you posted is not valid JSON. See https://json.org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a script expects data in specific format, you often have to map your data to fit format. This can be modified in server code or using javascript

Can use jQuery `$.map` to reconfigure an object or array to another array.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qpsSe/1

**Note that trailing commas in sample JSON need removing to validate JSON**

```
/* "json" is your response object, modify variable names to match */
var chartData=$.map( json, function( obj,i){
        return [[ obj.status, obj.val]];                            
})
```

**[$.map API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)**

Alternate method in native javascript

```
var chartData=[];
for( i=0; i<json.length; i++){
   chartData.push( [ json[i]['status'], json[i]['val'] ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a very complete and thoughtful answer!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that's just how Highcharts wants its data. That being said, the parser is pretty easy:

```
var data;  // this is your received data
var highchartsData = []; // this is data for highcharts

$.each(data, function(i, e) {
    highchartsData.push([e.status, e.val]);
});
```

One thing to note is that if the data you're receiving is in text (say, a response from an AJAX call) then you need to convert it to a javascript object like so:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(textData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a parser when assigning options as [stated in HighCharts preprocessing](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#preprocessing)
Basically, you parse the data and include it in the options:

```
var serie1 = json.map( function(e) {
    return [e.status, e.val];
});
options.series.push({data: serie1});
```

[Here is a working example using $.map and options in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdejuan/SREcf/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Since Highcharts 3.0, categories can also be extracted by giving each point a name and setting axis type to "category".

For a column bar chart this would be:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
    },

    series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            color: '#00FF00',
            y: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            color: '#FF00FF',
            y: 5
        }]
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind chart with JSON data, directly.
You just need to set the json property names as highchart standard.
'Y' for value and 'name' for label.

Your JSON should be as like follow:

```
[
    {
        name: "Stopped \/ Idle",
        y: 17.469444444444
    }, {
        name: "Working",
        y: 0
    }, {
        name: "Headland Turning",
        y: 0
    }, {
        name: "Transport",
        y: 0.15333333333333
    }
]
```