# Parsing JSON data for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, pie-chart

I have been going in circles for a few hours with this and have exhausted all the similar stackoverflow threads and also highcharts docs, so hopefully someone can help.

I am trying to plot a pie chart with a gender split. I have worked with line charts before and so had my data in the format for x and y axis, like this:

```
[{"y":"Mr","x":"145"},{"y":"Miss","x":"43"},{"y":"Mrs","x":"18"},{"y":"Ms","x":"2"}]
```

This was getting me somewhere, i could tap into the json and pull out the ints but i couldnt for the life of me get the titles associated with the figures...

```
function genderData() {
 $.getJSON('/statsboard/gender', function(data_g) {
    $.each(data_g, function(key_g, val_g) {
        obj_g = val_g;
         genderChart.series[0].addPoint(parseInt(obj_g.x));

        //genderChart.xAxis[0].categories.push(obj_g.y);
    });
 });
}
```

I then just called the function genderData as follows:

```
genderChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'gender',
            events: {
                load: genderData
            }
        }
        title: {
            text: 'Gender Split'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            },
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Gender Split',
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

So i ended up with an accurate chart but with out the labels, and they would just default to 'slice'...

So close but no cigar ;-)

Soooo i altered my serverside code to return the following format as per the docs :-), now returning the following:

```
[{"Mr":"145"},{"Miss":"43"},{"Mrs":"18"},{"Ms":"2"}]
```

This looks pretty much spot on to me, but alas, when i try to accomodate for this on the js code, everything falls apart.

I have been looking at this:
[Write JSON parser to format data for pie chart (HighCharts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252424/write-json-parser-to-format-data-for-pie-chart-highcharts)

but cant get the practice applied here to fit my circumstances.. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your points as follows:

```
    genderChart.series[0].addPoint({

        name: key_g,
        y: val_g

    });
```

Comment: is this using the json in the later form? [{"Mr":"145"},...

If so, where have name: and y: come from? As it not seeming to work atm...

Comment: Yes. Place this code in your 'genderData' function, replacing the original call to 'addPoint'.  The 'name' and 'y' are properties set on the point object that is passed to 'addPoint'. The point is represented here as a literal json object.

Comment: ok i got there in the end, with help from both of you, in the end i need to specify and typecast the integer...

function genderData() {
 $.getJSON('/statsboard/gender', function(data_g) {
    $.each(data_g, function(key_g, val_g) {
        obj_g = val_g;
         genderChart.series[0].addPoint({
            name: obj_g.name,
            y: parseInt(obj_g.y)

    });
        console.log(obj_g.y)
    });
 });
}

With a bit of console logging i was able to get there! Thanks so much!

Comment: if i have 2 y axis? i.e. one x axis and two y axes!

Comment: In a pie chart two yAxis..?

Answer (score 3):

The forms:

```
[{"name": "Mr", "y": 145}, ...]
```

or

```
[["Mr", 145], ...]
```

will work. Notice the second form is an array of *arrays* not an array of *objects* (you were close).

See [basic-pie demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) (click view options and scroll down to data), [series.data docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data), and [series.addPoint docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#object-Series) for more info.

If you make the server side return the data in one of the two above forms you can just do:

```
function genderData() {
  $.getJSON('/statsboard/gender', function(data_g) {
    genderChart.series[0].setData(data_g, true);
  });
}
```

Comment: hi Chad, thanks for this, its making some progress, with json in the following form: 

[{"name":"Mr","y":"145"},{"name":"Miss","y":"43"},{"name":"Mrs","y":"18"},{"name":"Ms","y":"2"}]

I am getting an error:

Uncaught Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14 


ive had a look through the docs you recommended but as it always referes to static data im not sure where im going wrong, but ill keep looking...

Comment: That is because your values need to be numbers, not strings. It needs to be `[{"y": 43}, ...]` not `[{"y": "43"}, ...]`

Comment: Right, i got it, in the end i did the typecasting in the js side of things as it wasnt so easy to get at in the backend, between your help and @Greg i made it..

Answer (score 1):

By rearranging my Json to have "name" and "y" as the keys i was able to make progress i.e:

```
[{"name":"Mr","y":"145"},{"name":"Miss","y":"43"},{"name":"Mrs","y":"18"},{"name":"Ms","y":"2"}]
```

Then by looping through the json data and parsing the "y" value as a int with the function parseInt() in the JS i was able to get my desired result...

```
function genderData() {
$.getJSON('/statsboard/gender', function(data_g) {
$.each(data_g, function(key_g, val_g) {
    obj_g = val_g;
     genderChart.series[0].addPoint({
        name: obj_g.name,
        y: parseInt(obj_g.y)
});
console.log(obj_g.y)
});
});
}
```

Comment: If theres a prettier way to do this im all ears, but its up and running now at least ;-)

Comment: more efficient would be to make the values numbers server-side, so you don't have to iterate the object twice. But with a small object like this, it isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: duly noted, thanks for your help on this chad, it was appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been solved. but the map function for array might be a good choice in these cases, I love map in functional language!

```
data = [{"y":"Mr","x":"145"},{"y":"Miss","x":"43"},
        {"y":"Mrs","x":"18"},{"y":"Ms","x":"2"}];

var series = data.map(function(e){ return parseInt(e.x); });
```

.... hight chart ....